# Third party json formatting function is not working as expected

Tags: php, json

I have the following json array.

```
     { "files": [ { "Name": "4c9c49b73bd3a", "Attributes": {
 "title": "Winter.jpg", "file_size":
 "105542", "url":
 "http:\/\/dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net\/4c9c49b73bd3a.jpg",
 "file_name": "4c9c49b73bd3a.jpg",
 "time_stamp": "1285310908",
 "file_type": "image\/jpeg",
 "content_obj_type": "upload", "thumb":
 "http:\/\/dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net\/4c9c49b73bfef.jpg",
 "width": "183.13253012048193",
 "height": "169", "userid": "1",
 "gibid": "1", "contentid":
 "4c9c49b73bd3a", "qqfile":
 "Winter.jpg", "original_name":
 "Winter.jpg", "y":
 "44.51666259765625", "x": "626",
 "on_floor": "false", "success":
 "true", "gibview": "O", "resize":
 "true" } }, { "Name": "4ce4fbb33c388",
 "Attributes": { "title": "Rediff 1",
 "file_size": "", "url":
 "http:\/\/rediff.com\/", "file_name":
 "", "time_stamp": "1290075059",
 "file_type": "html",
 "content_obj_type": "link", "thumb":
 "http:\/\/dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net\/4ce4fbb010e92.html",
 "width": "100", "height": "100",
 "link": "rediff.com", "userid": "1",
 "gibid": "1", "contentid":
 "4ce4fbb33c388", "y": "611", "x":
 "233", "on_floor": "true", "success":
 "true", "gibview": "O" } } ],
 "success": "true", "message": null }
```

i am using the the json_format function of [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) page

```
echo json_format(json_encode($array));
```

Please suggest what is the problem why this json is not getting formatted.

Comment: you got the json , you got the function , and you got a problem ? please what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: @poelinca this function is not doing formatting.

Comment: try to describe your problem!

Comment: The guy who wrote the function you copied states that he wrote it in 10 minues, maybe he didn't even test it. You can hardly expect the community to debug another guys function for you unless you show your own initiative at doing so which means opening a question where you show what you found out so far and where you have trouble.

Comment: whar error messages do you get what is the output how does the page with the code look like etc etc.. be more precis

Comment: If you just have to format it once, JSONLint (http://www.jsonlint.com/) is a nice way to go.

Comment: I dont think php contains a function called `json_format`, so it must be user defined function, what does this do?

Comment: @Starx: as I said in my comment, it IS a user function posted in the php manual discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

echo json_format(json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));

Comment: could you tell more info. what is returning null?

Comment: json_encode is returning nothing and format function returning null